# How should I read the exported bookmarks from Firefox?

Tags: php, linux

I want to develop a software that uses the bookmarks.html to automatically create thumbs or a presentation page from the bookmarks that were exported from firefox or etc, maybe an api that makes this work easy.

I would like to know which is the best method of reading a html file like if it was xml.

Or maybe if this api already exists?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just use the XML parser - if it's properly structured, it should work

Comment: @Pekka: I think he's referring to the old Netscape standard, which is extremely invalid.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be able to use DOMDocument's loadHTML method.  It doesn't care if it's well-formed or not.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Edit:
Or loadHTMLFile of course: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php